# Spark dataframe : join approach for derived columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataset as you see in below code (`df`), my requirement is to be able to add a derived column (`DerivedCol`). This column's value is constant for a `idcol` group of rows and is derived by application of a) predicate on another column's value(`filter` here), and then b) an aggregation function (`max` used here) over the matching group.

```
val df = Seq(("id1","k1","7"),("id2","k1","5"),("id1","k3","2"),("id3","k1","4"),("id2","k5","1"),("id4","k5","1"))
  .toDF("idcol","keycol","valcol")

val aggDf = df.filter($"keycol" === "k1")
  .select($"idcol",$"valcol")
  .groupBy($"idcol")
  .agg(max($"valcol".cast(IntegerType)).cast(StringType).as("DerivedCol"))
  .withColumnRenamed("idcol", "newidcol")

df.join(aggDf, df("idcol") === aggDf("newidcol"), "left_outer")
  .drop(aggDf("newidcol"))
```

I am using a `left outer join` for this. My dataset is very huge (millions of rows). I have below questions:

1. Is there any other approach to achieve this?
2. What partitioning logic should I use to reduce shuffles?

The cardinality of the `idcol` column is very high. Spark version is 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other approach to achieve this?

There is - window functions.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn(
   "derivedcol",  
   max($"valcol".cast(IntegerType)).over(Window.partitionBy($"idcol")
)
```

Depending on:

- The cardinality - high cardinality is good.
- The distribution of sizes of the groups - small groups without large positive skews are good.

this might behave somewhat better or much worse than aggregation followed by join.

> What partitioning logic should I use to reduce shuffles?

Probably none. There are at least two reasons:

- If you have large number of small groups window functions will do fine and there is no need for additional partitioning.
- If you have small number of larger groups data should be broadcasted and the only shuffle required is for aggregation.
- If there is a large number of large groups - you might consider pre-partitioning by id, but depending on the number of factors, you can at both loose and gain, and no additional shuffle (partitioning) is on average better.